# Limit of transition probabilities as n goes to infinity

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, markov-chains

Consider the random walk on $S = \{0,1, \ldots, N\}$ such that $p(i,i+1) = p$ and $p(i,i-1) = 1-p$ for $1 \leq i \leq N-1$, whereas $p(0,1) = 1 = p(N,N-1)$, where $p(i,j)$ denotes the transition probabilities. I'd like to know whether the sequence $p_n(i,j)$ converges as $n \rightarrow \infty$, where $p_n(i,j)$ denotes the probability of going from state $i$ to state $j$ in $n$ steps.

I know that the chain is irreducible and has period $2$, so even though it has a stationary distribution $\pi$ (because it is finite and irreducible), we might not have $\lim p_n(i,j) = \pi(j)$ for all $j \in S$. I have tried to analyse $p_n(0,0)$, for example. If $n$ is odd, then $p_n(0,0) = 0$, however I can't find an easy way to calculate this for even $n$ as the number of cases starts getting quite complicated.

I tried, then, to look at the problem numerically, and I saw that for $N = 5$ and $p = 1/3$, for example, $p_{2n}(0,0)$ converges to, roughly, $0.5161$, so the sequence $p_n(0,0)$ does not converge. I did this by calculating powers of the transition matrix, but I can't formalize the argument for the general case. How can I guarantee that $p_{2n+1}(0,0)$ does not approach zero as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: Define $p_n(i,j)$.

Comment: I've edited the question with the definition. The definition of $p_n(i,j)$ is the probability of going from state $i$ to state $j$ in $n$ steps.

Comment: You said the period is 2, this immediately means $p_{2n+1}(0,0)=0$. Actually it also means that for any $(i,j)$ either transitioning from I to j in an even number of steps or an odd number of steps is impossible.

Comment: have you tried diagonalizing $ p(i,j) $ similar to this work https://scholarworks.calstate.edu/downloads/6395w909v case by case?

Comment: Off hand guess: $p_n(i,j)\to \frac{1}{N+1}$  Idea - things keep getting mixed up.  At least $p_n(i,j)\to q(j)$ independent of $i$.

Comment: The stationary distribution is not uniform. Because look at the probability current into and out of the state $N-1$ in the uniform case. The current out is $1/(N+1)$ (you never stay), the current in is $p/(N+1)+1/(N+1)$. Thus starting from a uniform distribution, $N-1$ becomes more likely than it was after one time step. In any case what actually happens here is $p_n(i,j) \to \begin{cases} 2 \pi_j & |i-j| \text{ has the same parity as } n \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise} \end{cases}$.